# Is 'natural neighbor' interpolation better than linear for unstructured function interpolation?

Tags: interpolation

Natural neighbor interpolation is defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_neighbor_interpolation), it is an intriguing method that uses voronoi diagrams. Notably it is smooth almost everywhere whereas linear interpolation is only piecewise linear. I was using it for my research but after some playing around it seems to just be... worse than linear. Here is a pic of natural neighbor vs linear from my research and the first derivative. The derivative of the natural neighbor interpolation is blunted because it is singular at the sampling points.

[image]
The data here is 2D and I interpolated along a line that included many sampling points.

Does Natural Neighbor interpolation beat linear interpolation at anything?

Comment: From your leftmost figure it looks like the NN-interpolation dips down to be *lower* than both neighbouring datapoints, which should not be possible for a correct implementation. It's also clearly not smooth at the datapoints. I think you simply have a bug when computing the weights.

Comment: this is a built in matlab function, I don't think there is a bug.  There is a lower weight off the sampling line that is causing the value to dip down.

Answer (score 1):

The main advantage of this interpolation technique is that it's independent of whatever meshing you'd have to pick for linear interpolation.

A typical extreme example would be a perfect square, where you have to pick over which diagonal you want to interpolate, and results may differ greatly;

```matlab
P = [0 0; 0 1; 1 0; 1 1];
V = [0; 0; 0; 1];
F = scatteredInterpolant(P,V)
[X,Y] = meshgrid(linspace(0,1,50), linspace(0,1,50));

F.Method = 'linear'
V2lin = reshape(F([X(:),Y(:)]), 50,50)
surf(X,Y,V2lin)
% vs
figure(2)
F.Method = 'natural'
V2nat = reshape(F([X(:),Y(:)]), 50,50)
surf(X,Y,V2nat)
```

[image: linear interpolation]
[image: natural interpolation]

Playing around with a more complete unstructured mesh

```matlab
P = [0 0; 0 1; 1 0; 1 1; rand(20,2)];
V = P(:,1) .* P(:,2) + rand(size(V))*0.1
F = scatteredInterpolant(P,V)
...
```

[image: bumpy linear interpolation]
[image: bumpy natural interpolation]
the natural interpolation looks "better", and i certainly don't see any unnatural dips that aren't there in the source data; after all, the weights to the surrounding datapoints always sums up to exactly 1.
I can only assume something unexpected is happening to the datapoints outside the slice you showed, or the there is some bug in the code.